# in spring mvc how to call action by javascript passing form object

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a common scenario. I have a list page. There are three buttons. View, edit and delete.
Each record has a radio button which selects id of that record.

```
    $(".radioBtn input").click(function() {
        $('#messageId').val(this.value);
    });
```

also I am keeping the id as hidden field to set it in the form object

```
    <form:form id="messageForm" commandName="message">
            <form:hidden path="messageId" id="messageId" />
    </form:form>
```

When I click on any radio, it is set in form object. Now different action needs to be invoked on clicking of view or edit or delete button.
I can't user ajax. I need to call them by plain javascript so that i can render the result in different page returned by view of ModelAndView.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have this three buttons (view, edit, delete) for each item in the list (so when the list has 5 items, you have 15 buttons in total)?

Comment: no. buttons are at the end of the page. only three buttons. It all are working fine. I just need to submit the form with javascript. i am trying to get document.form.action to hold action mapping name and document.form.submit() to submit it but it ain't working.

Comment: But why do you submit the from with java script when you want to display the returned html. Instead you could submit the form with a normal html submit button, then the browser will render the returned html, so there is no javascript needed?

Comment: javascript was needed because i have multiple buttons. html submit is linked with a particular action. Nevertheless I got the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665054/javascript-form-submit-not-working.   Ralph, thanks anyway man.